# Schedule read operation in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

What is the best solution for scheduling periodic background function calls in Tornado? I thought about using tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089086/unexpected-tornado-ioloop-periodiccallback-behavior). Can spawn_callback be used for scheduling like [this](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)? What I want to achieve is a simple server which, besides its other duties, periodically fetches information from a system within the local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PeriodicCallback` is probably the simplest solution as long as you don't need to worry about the case where the task runs for longer than its scheduled period.

```
@gen.coroutine
def refresh()
    resp = yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url)
    ...

def main():
    ...
    PeriodicCallback(refresh, 3600).start()
    ...
```

If you are concerned about overruns, I'd probably wrap the whole thing in a loop:

```
@gen.coroutine
def refresh_loop(interval=3600):
    next_time = IOLoop.current().time()
    while True:
        next_time += interval
        yield refresh()
        while next_time <= IOLoop.current().time():
            next_time += interval
        yield gen.Task(IOLoop.current().call_at, next_time)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! Since you've set 3600 as interval: The ~4s delay pointed out in the linked thread I didn't understand. Does this mean that if I set it to e.g. 333 the intervals differ a bit, but the number of requests is roughly equal to 3 per second (not a problem), or is 3600 the shortest possible interval length?

Comment: 3600 (one hour) was just an example; you can use any interval including sub-second fractions. But the shorter the interval the more likely you are too have problems with overruns.